# How to use to two deserialization techniques with same class names

Tags: flutter, dart, deserialization, flutter-web, flatbuffers

In my project I am trying to use both Json based deserialization and flatbuffer based desrialization. 
For example following Json from a back-end api could be deserialized to a class named `ModelInfo` say using `freezed` package. Assume this class is defined in `freezed_model.dart`

```js
{
 "model_name":"Model A",
 "model_size": 50
}
```

Now from the same back end I want to send this information as bytearray using flatbuffer serialization. With the `flatc` I can generate the code which deserializes this to another class with the same name`ModelInfo` with identical information. Assume this class is available in `flatbuffer_model.dart`

I would like to utilize these classes across UI layer, managers or api layers in a flutter project without conflicting `imports`. For example if my widget uses the `ModelInfo` class I would prefer it to be dynamically resolved during compile and run time from either `freezed_model.dart` or `flatbuffer_model.dart`. Maybe this is not possible, but asking out wouldn't hurt i believe.

I tried conditional imports and conditional exports but the dart analyzer is not happy with it and I am sure my approach is wrong.

for e.g. I defined a class called `environment.dart` as follows.

```dart
import 'package:scandal_view/src/config_reader.dart';

enum Environment { PROD, DEV }

class CurrentEnvironment {
  static Environment _environment;
  /// assigning a default _decodeMode thinking dart analyser be able to resolve classes during 
  ///conditional export or import.
  static String _decodeMode = 'flatbuffers';

  static void initialize(Environment environment) {
    _environment = environment;
    // reassigns the _decomeMode during runTime.
    _decodeMode = ConfigReader.getDecodemode();
  }

  static Environment get environment => _environment;
  static String get decodeMode => _decodeMode;
}
```

After this in my api class I tried to do the following conditional import but it doesn't work.

```dart
import 'dummy_model.dart' 
      if(CurrentEnvironment.decodeMode == 'json') 
            'package:mypackage/lib/model/json/freezed_model.dart'
      if(CurrentEnvironment.decodeMode == 'flatbuffer') 
            'package:mypackage/lib/model/flatbuffers/flatbuffer_model.dart'
```

As of now my `dummy_model.dart` is empty. Earlier I used it to export same files mentioned above but it didn't help. I am thinking of using facade patter for this, but that would lead to too much hand written code and error prone where as the deserializers are autogenerated and safe.

Answer (score 2):

If I didn't understand bad, what you are trying to achieve is decoupling your ModelInfo class from the serialisation/deserialisation approach you choose (be it json, flat buffers etc), right?

If that's the case your proposal of conditional imports will not work (and if it does I think it wouldn't be a good option when it comes to maintaining it, testing it or scaling it.

My proposal would be to follow some sort of Repository pattern in the most simple possible way. This would allow you to really decouple how you obtain your data from your consumer, which would allow you to choose the serialising/deserialising strategy or even have multiple serialisers etc. This approach would also make super easy to add persistence/cache to your app in the future, should you need it.

Let's imagine a simple scenario where you want to fetch a list of ModelInfo objects to be consumed by your business layer (View Models, blocs etc) and then your UI.

Let start by assuming we have a ModelInfo class which is the target one (the one we want to send to the upper layers of our App from the services layer).

```
class ModelInfo {
    // This is the model we want to expose to our upper layers (View Models, Blocs etc) 
}
```

1) First we would create an interface to define the contract that every ApiDataManager would implement. In Dart we use Abstract Classes for that:

```
abstract class ApiDataManager {
  List<ModelInfo> fetchItems();
}
```

2 - Now we can create as many Api data managers as we want (json, flatbuffers etc) as long as they conform to `ApiDataManager`. On those managers we can import the needed libraries and do the corresponding api calls, parsing etc. As long as we have a `fetchItems()`method that returns `List<ModelInfo>` we are fine.

```
class jsonApi implements ApiDataManager {

    List<ModelInfo> fetchItems() {
     /* Here you implement a fetchItem method that parses your json server response
     *  and returns an ItemModel list */
    }

}

class flatBuffersApi implements ApiDataManager {
     List<ModelInfo> fetchItems() {
     /* Here you implement a fetchItem method that parses your flatbuffers server response
      *  and returns an ItemModel list */
    }
}
```

3 - Now we create a repository where we'll inject the remote API data provider you want to use (json, flatbuffers). This repository will be used by our View Models, Blocs etc, to fetch the data and get back fully fledged model objects.

```
class Repository {

  final ApiDataManager remoteDataManager;

  Repository(this.remoteDataManager);


  List<ModelInfo> fetchItems() {

    // Call remoteDataManager.fetchItems()
    // Depending on the remote data manager you have injected you'll be 
    // using json endpoints or flatbuffers, or whatever you want!
    // Return the list to your view models, Blocs etc

    return remoteDataManager.fetchItems();
  }

}
```

4 - And finally we can consume our Repository from our business or presentation layer (our Widget) and get our list of ModelInfo objects. We can actually dynamically inject the Api type we want at runtime depending on the logic you want to use. You would use some logic like this in your ViewModel, bloc or Widget:

```
// Imagine this is inside your Widget or View Model or bloc

bool isProd = false; // Whatever you want to use to control the logic

var myJsonApi = JsonApi();
var myFlatBuffersApi = FlatBuffersApi();

var apiToUse = isProd ? JsonApi() : FlatBuffersApi();

Repository myRepository = Repository(apiToUse);

// Here you have your fresh list of items!
List<ModelInfo> myItems =  myRepository.fetchItems();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and detailed answer. I am aware of this adapter pattern. I am trying to avoid manually writing the code for the model. As you said this import based approach will not work. I will keep looking for more solution. I found this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-design-patterns-2-adapter-3f05c02a7c84) which explains you approach. As of now I will upvote your answer so that similar requests could refer this answer. This is one of the correct solution but not what I am looking for.